# How to Extend Membership in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am wondering how do I extend the membership stuff in asp.net?

When a user logs in I want to check the UserName and Password. Of course the standard asp.net membership does this(this it is ValidateUser()).

I also want to check another field called "institution". If a user types something in this box I want to verify if the "institution", "userName" and "password" match what is in the database.

If a user leaves the "institution" blank then I just want to use it default ValidateUser() method that is provided in asp.net and check only "userName" and "password".

So can I overload the ValdiateUser() method? Or will I have to write my own one to handle this new case?

Where would I store this "institution" field in the database? I heard something about people recommending the "Profile" table but I am not sure.

Also how can I change the membership to treat these as 3 different users

Institution: ABC
UserName: A09410515
Password: 1234567

Institution: GHA
UserName: A09410515
Password: 1234567

UserName: A09410515
Password: 1234567

So as my database should be concerned these should be 3 unique users. Of course in the case that my database already would have the same information stored in it.

For example.

Institution: ABC
UserName: A09410515
Password: 1234567

and someone tries to sign up with the exact same information for "UserName" and "Institution" then it would spit back an error about being duplicate names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can [create a custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).  Your provider will implement [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) giving you full control over creating an interface between the membership system and extended database schema.  [Writing A Custom Membership Provider for your ASP.NET 2.0 Web Site](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256) is a detailed example.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the links. I am still a bit confused though. Where do I store these extra fields that I would be adding. Like do I add it to the profile or what?

Like I am making a custom provider so that I can merge my asp.net db and my db together but I am using mssql server.

Also I noticed they override that methods. I still want to use the default verify method. So do I make 2 overload methods. One with my custom verify and one method calling the default verify method?

Answer (score 2):

The lazy way of doing this would be to combine institution and username together to create the actual username.

Thus you'd have 3 distinct usernames: ABC&A09410515, GHA&A09410515, and &A09410515. Just don't allow a user to use & in a username.

Then, before creating the user or logging in you just combine the two strings together.

I can't think of any significant problems that can't be fixed with a simple hack (e.g. displaying the username (use *username.split('&')[1]* ), but JP's post is definitely the "right" way to do it.

James

Answer (score 1):

You might use Application Name as the institution, that way you would have the same user name in different applications

Rodrigo.